# TRUNCATE does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Does anybody know why this SQL query doesn't clear my table (table name in the variable `$datetoday`)
the queries after it does work, whats wrong? right now $datetoday = 300313

```
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE `data`.`".$datetoday."`');
```

EDIT :
the error is :

```
Could not clear table: Table 'data.".$datetoday."' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the table name?

Comment: of cuorse :) - 300313 (ddmmyy)

Comment: The error message generated by mysql_error() would be very helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @jacobwalker0814 just edited

Comment: @MichaelRushton has the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE `data`.`' . $datetoday . '`');
```

You're enclosing the query in `'` but then using `"` around `$datetoday`.

Comment: thanks, but now the error is "Could not clear table: Incorrect table name '' "

Comment: Then `$datetoday` is undefined (or an empty string/`null`/a boolean, etc).

Comment: cen't beleve i didn't checked it , any way I also used your solotion, thank you !